# Bug in awarding "First Responder" hat

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

I was awarded the "First Responder" hat late yesterday on Community Building.

[image: First Responder hat, Epiphany hat]

As you can see the hat was awarded **later** than "Epiphany" (Jan 6th).

This is because there is a bug (or loophole) in the way the "First Responder" hat is awarded:

1. The room parent site - in this case for [Ye Olde Hat Shoppe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe) was changed yesterday by the room owner to communitybuilding.stackexchange.com as an experiment.
2. Everybody with a starred message in Ye Olde Hat Shoppe who also had a account on Community Building was then awarded the hat (on Jan 6th).

Note: The parent site has now been reverted to the default (no parent site).

It might be something to fix for Winter Bash 2017.

Comment: *It might be something to fix for Winter Bash 2017* That is nice of you. It gives plenty of 6 to 8 weeks time frames to get a fix out...

Comment: Cliché though it is, I'd be tempted to call this a feature, not a bug. Presumably everyone who was awarded the hat did actually *have* a starred message +/- 12h of New Year, so the conditions for awarding it are fulfilled. I think it's a good idea that you get your hat once the room has a parent site that the hat can be tied to.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I can agree with that ...

Comment: @rene actually it is _It might be someting to fix to Winter Bash 2016_.